# Getting a ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing a `search` method in a controller, and I keep getting this error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in TripsController#search

Extracted source (around line #22):
```

The offending line is within the following block:

```
if params[:search].present?
  @trips = Trip.where("destination LIKE :destination",  {:destination=> "%#{params[:search].first}%"}).where(@filters)
else
  @trips = (Trip.where(@filters)) rescue (Trip.where(@filters).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10))
end
```

Below is the full method code:

```
  def search
    @languages = Trip.pluck(:language).uniq
    @interests = Trip.pluck(:interests).uniq
    @destinations = Trip.pluck(:destination).uniq

    @filters = params.slice(:language,:interests)
    @search_param = params[:search].first rescue nil
    @language_param = params[:language]
    @intersts_param = params[:interests]

    if params[:search].present?
      @trips = Trip.where("destination LIKE :destination",  {:destination=> "%#{params[:search].first}%"}).where(@filters)
    else
      @trips = (Trip.where(@filters)) rescue (Trip.where(@filters).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10))
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Rails strong parameters.
Even if you are not using the parameters to to create a model Rails will raise an exception if you use `params.slice` and pass the result to a query.

This is due of the pretty pro-active approach that came with Rails 4 to avoid mass-assignment vulnerabilities.

```
def search
  @languages = Trip.pluck(:language).uniq
  @interests = Trip.pluck(:interests).uniq
  @destinations = Trip.pluck(:destination).uniq
  @filters = params.permit(:language,:interests)
  @search_param = params.permit(search: [])
  @language_param = @filters[:language]
  @intersts_param = @filters[:interests]

  if params[:search].present?
    # you don't need named placeholders for a single parameter...
    @trips = Trip.where("destination LIKE ?", params[:search].first)
                 .where(@filters)
  else
    @trips = (Trip.where(@filters)) rescue (Trip.where(@filters).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10))
  end
end
```

However in `.where(@filters)` you are breaking a cardinal rule and passing user input straight into a SQL query.

Instead you should use something like this:

```
Trip.where(language: @filters[:language])
```

This will create a "WHERE trips.language = ?" query with a placeholder which removes the SQL injection vulnerability.